# JQuery button click only works 1st time

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the below JQuery code on a Rails 5 app.  Works fine if I check the box the first time.  Also works fine if I uncheck the same checkbox.  But when I reclick the same box I initially clicked, it no longer checks off the box.   Anything I'm missing in my code below?

```
$(".filter-wrapper-f").click(function(){
    var $checkbox = $(this).children(".checkpic");
    if ($checkbox.attr('checked')){
        $checkbox.removeAttr('checked');
    } else {
        $checkbox.attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

I've also tried this and it won't work to start with.

```
$(".filter-wrapper-f").click(function(){
var $checkbox = $(this).children(".checkpic");
    if ($checkbox.prop('checked', true)){
        $checkbox.removeProp('checked');
    } else {
        $checkbox.prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: use `prop()` like `$checkbox.prop('checked', true);`

Comment: change `attr` to `prop` - either `$checkbox.prop('checked', false)` or `$checkbox.prop('checked', true)`

Comment: @BenKolyaMansley @guradio I tried both but now the initial function doesn't even check the box in the first place.  `        var $checkbox = $(this).children(".checkpic");
        if ($checkbox.prop('checked', true)){
         $checkbox.removeProp('checked');
        } else {
         $checkbox.prop('checked', true);
        }
    });`

Comment: Replace removeProp with `prop('checked',false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), `prop` should be used to set the `checked` attribute.

`$checkbox.prop('checked', true)`

Explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/5551783

Comment: I tried this but even the initial formula doesn't work with this.  I'll edit code so you can see.